# Setting different variable for serialization and deserialization

Tags: spring, jackson

I am trying to achieve lazy load with foreign key association in spring4
I want to serialize the entity with id while deserialize with customer entity.
Below is my entity.

I am getting exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "customerId"
```

Why is this so? And what can i do to achieve this scenario.

```
public class Address {


@JsonIgnore
public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}
@JsonProperty("customerId")
public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Customer.class)
@JoinColumn(name="customerId", insertable=false, updatable = false)
@JsonIgnore
Customer customer;

@JsonProperty
public int getCustomerIdGen() {
    return customerIdGen;
}
@JsonIgnore
public void setCustomerIdGen(int customerId) {
    this.customerIdGen = customerId;

}

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name="customerId")
int customerIdGen;
String contactName;

}
```

Comment: So you're serializing to `{"customerId":1234}`, but deserializing something like  `{"customerId": {"name":"example", "age":"other"}}` ?

Comment: yep so that spring can take care of the foreign key constraint

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom deserializer, something like this:

```
public class Address {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomerDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("customerId")
    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    ...
}
```

And here is the deserializer

```
public class CustomerDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Customer>{

    @Override
    public Customer deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        int customerId = jsonparser.getInt();

        // Now create or find the way to get the customer object
        Customer c = new Customer(customerId);
        return c;
    }
}
```